# How to create single vertex using given coordinate?

Tags: python, vertices

I want to create single point do not rely on any object using script, but I didn't find corresponding option about this in blender. If we can't do this in blender, I hope to create a plane if its four vertices coordinates were given. How to realize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate the addon *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* from *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Add-Ons*.

[image]

Then you can add a *Single Vert* from the *Add* menu.

[image]

Comment: Fun fact, the tooltip says add a single "vertice" which is commonly used, but not actually a word. :)

Comment: It says 'Add single Vertice to Edit mode' both in Object and Edit mode here which makes even less sense! :^)